# imagebutton inside fragment nullPoint Exception

Tags: android, android-fragments, imageview

I am putting ImageView inside Fragment. I have other question also but cannot find useful.
this is my code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_contect,container,false);
        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton)getView().findViewById( R.id.ib);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity( new Intent( getActivity(), Enquiry.class ) );
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I provide solution of your issue, please check that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to  do like this in **getview()** you getting null pointer exception use view.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_contect,container,false);
   ImageButton imageButton = v.findViewById(R.id.ib);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity( new Intent( getActivity(), Enquiry.class ) );
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You got NullPointException because of using `getview()`:

```
ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton)getView().findViewById( R.id.ib);
```

**Solution:** use `v` instead of `getView()`

```
ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById( R.id.ib);
```

[Android Fragment Referance](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#getView())